# How to check if my Mouse is inside a rectangle?

Tags: java, eclipse

my goal is, that if my mouse is inside a square, that exact suqare lights up. But that isnt happening. If i move my mouse in the lower right corner all squares light up.

I've already looked up a similar post to this, but it didnt quite help me.

this is the code of my mouse class

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    int mouseX = e.getX();
    int mouseY = e.getY();
    for (int y = 100; y < 500; y += 106) {
        for (int x = 10; x < 700; x += 86) {
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(x + 2, y + 2, x + 80, y + 100);
            if (mouseX > rec.getMinX() && mouseX < rec.getMaxX() 
                            && mouseY > rec.getMinY() && mouseY < rec.getMaxY())
                    {
                        GUI.MousePos = true;
                    } else {
                        GUI.MousePos = false;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code of my GUI class, where I create the rectangles and the colors

```
for (int y = 100; y < 500; y += 106) {
    for (int x = 10; x < 700; x += 86) {
        if (counter != Tag.MaxDay()) {
            if (Tag.getArray(counter) == dayOfMonth - 1 && MousePos == true){
                g.setColor(myGreenSpecial);
            } 
            else if (Tag.getArray(counter) == dayOfMonth - 1 && MousePos == false)
                g.setColor(myGreen_Date);
            else if (MousePos == true)
                g.setColor(myGreen_Date);
            else {
                g.setColor(myGreen);
            }
            g.fillRoundRect(x + 2, y + 2, 80, 100, 10, 10); // tage rechteck
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawRoundRect(x + 2, y + 2, 80, 100, 10, 10);
            counter++;
            g.drawString("" + counter, x + 10, y + 70);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem lies in the fact that `GUI.MousePos` is a static variable - that is, it belongs to the class `GUI`, rather than identifying a particular part of the graphical user interface, which is more likely what you want. Therefore, when you change `MousePos` to `true` for one region, your logic that iterates over the regions always reads the value as `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your first block of code. You seem to be correctly identifying whether or not the mouse is inside the rectangles, but you aren't storing that information correctly. There's only one boolean, `GUI.MousePos`, that's trying to track the state of every rectangle. In effect, every rectangle is set to be highlighted the same way, and only the last value (the bottom right corner) is actually displayed.

You either need to change that to an array of booleans, one for each rectangle, or keep track of the index of the highlighted rectangle, instead of just using a boolean.